# Why my Mac is showing only 250 GB out of 500 GB?

Tags: mac, hard-drive, storage

I have MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2012)

It comes with a 500 GB hard but today when I checked it it's only showing 250 GB. Please tell me why is that?

[image]

Macintosh HD:

```
  Available: 81.57 GB (81,570,791,424 bytes)
  Capacity: 249.98 GB (249,984,860,160 bytes)
  Mount Point: /
  File System: Journaled HFS+
  Writable: Yes
  Ignore Ownership: No
  BSD Name: disk0s2
  Volume UUID: 805DC50A-074F-3D46-AEE2-0A3974FC8045
  Physical Drive:
      Media Name: APPLE HDD HTS545050A7E362 Media
      Medium Type: Rotational
      Protocol: SATA
      Internal: Yes
      Partition Map Type: GPT (GUID Partition Table)
      S.M.A.R.T. Status: Verified
```

**diskutil list**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check what Disk Utility shows. Probably for some reason the remaining space is not partitioned.

Also, get a good backup since an erase and reinstall should fix things.

Before you erase, boot to recovery HD and try to repair the Macintosh HD and also repair the drive itself.

Comment: Their disk is clearly partitioned correctly as shown by the output of `diskutil list`

Comment: @JMY1000 this might be the correct answer. Both system information and  Didk Ugility show 250 GB and not partitioned correctly. I know `diskutil` shows 500 but  you might need to redo things so DiskUtility is happy, too

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

First go to system preferences then click on spotlight then on privacy tab and add your Macintosh or macOS Hard Drive to the privacy tab now quit system preferences wait for 10 mins then again go to system preferences and remove your Hard Drive/SSD from the privacy tab.

What this basically does is that it reindexes your Hard!

See if it works or not!